# How to select and separate comma values in XSLT

Tags: xslt

My XML:

```
<geoCode>36.113,-114.925</geoCode>
```

I need a XSLT which converts the above XML to below XML format:

```
<geoCode>
    <lati>36.113</lati>
    <longi>-114.925</longi>
</geoCode>
```

Comment: This is trivial: use `substring-before()` and `substring-after()`.

Comment: Hi, could you please confirm an answer if they worked for you? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code in your template:

```
<xsl:template match="...">
    <xsl:variable name="geo-code-split" select="tokenize(geoCode, ',')" />

    <geoCode>
        <lati><xsl:value-of select="$geo-code-split[1]" /></lati>
        <longi><xsl:value-of select="$geo-code-split[2]" /></longi>
    </geoCode>
</xsl:template>
```

P.S.: This solution uses XSLT 2.0. For XSLT 1.0, you can use the `string-before()` and `string-after()` functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
<geoCode>
    <lati>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(geoCode,',')"/>
    </lati>
    <longi>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(geoCode,',')"/>
    </longi>
</geoCode>
```

This is with substring-before and substring-after.